# Getting NullPointerException while looping DataFrame and access to outer scope variable

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

okay, I want to iterate DataFrame and operate each row with outer scope DataFrame variable but I am getting NullPointerException when I access to outer variable. here is my code

```
val outer: DataFrame = ...
val someDataFrame: DataFrame = ...
someDataFrame.foreach(row => {
    outer.show()
})
// this occurs java.lang.NullPointerException
```

here is another case

```
val outer: DataFrame = ...
val someDataFrame: DataFrame = ...
for(each <- someDataFrame) {
    outer.show()
}
// this occurs java.lang.NullPointerException
```

but it works with looping a List

```
val outer: DataFrame = ...
val list = List(1,2,3,4,5)
list.foreach(each => {
    outer.show()
})
// this prints outer 5 times
```

and this case it works too

```
val x = 1
val someDataFrame: DataFrame = ...
someDataFrame.foreach(row => {
    println(x)
})
// 1
```

I am using scala 2.11 and spark 2.3.0 and it seems like accessing to outer scope DataFrame only occurs NullPointerException. Can anyone explain why this happens ?

Comment: the problem is not that the variable is outer scope, but that it's a dataframe. You cannot use dataframes within a dataframe map/foreach (i.e. remote-code) function

Comment: Is there a way i can at least refer outer DataFrame ?

Comment: no. You should either join the dataframes or collect one (the smaller) e.g. as a plain scala `Map` and  then broadcast it.